# In the VSCode Integrated terminal, how can I run a custom command to activate an environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’m using vscode with the official/Microsoft python extension, and our firm uses a proprietary python wrapper. In essence, this means the only way we can activate virtual environments is through a script, call it `activate_env.sh` (which does environment creation and activation).

`conda/python` are not on the system level paths, and I don’t want to muck with that. I’ve pointed the extension to existing conda environments created from the script, so many features work nicely

When I create a new terminal, it automatically calls

`source activate`

`conda activate`

This triggers an error, for reasons I’ve mentioned above. Can I instead have it call my activation script on creating a new terminal session?